# Getting the value of select element in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a dropdown list of car brands and I want to pass the value of the selected car brand to method getCarModelsByBrand(brand). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <select (change)="getCarModelsByBrand($event.target.value)" class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option selected="" value="" selected disabled>Pasirinkite</option>
        <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" value=brand>{{brand}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ngModel](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel) with 2 way binding and bind to a property/field on the component along with [ngModelChange](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel) to trigger the selection has changed.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="modelOfSelectedBrandToBindTo" (ngModelChange)="getCarModelsByBrand($event)" id="sel1" name="sel1">
  <option value="" disabled>Pasirinkite</option>
  <option *ngFor="let brand of brands" [value]="brand">{{brand}}</option>
</select>
```

---

*I removed code that was not needed in the example to illustrate the point*

Comment: @greta - glad to help. Please consider marking an answer as "the answer" using the check-mark on the left side.

Comment: Did just that. However, there's a small problem - I just noticed the default "Pasirinkite" option has stopped working since I started using ngModel. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @greta - depends what you mean by stopped working? What is the default value of this item (null, empty string, something else)?

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that the selector is now blank when I first open the app. I want it to show "Pasirinkite" before anything is selected :)

Comment: @greta - got it. In your component make the model you are binding to (the assignment to `[(ngModel)]` have the initial value that the value `Pasirinkite` has. The value above is defined as an empty string so in your component that would be `modelOfSelectedBrandToBindTo: string = '';` where you define the model. Then the initial state of the model will match the default selection you want to show.

Comment: @greta - Glad to help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Remove the set value attribute from your option tag.

`<div class="form-group">
      <select (change)="getCarModelsByBrand($event.target.value)" class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <option selected="" value="" selected disabled>Pasirinkite</option>
        <option *ngFor="let brand of brands">{{brand}}</option>
      </select>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own and it works [My Personal site](http://www.alexmackinnon.ca) with the country select list for the globe.

```
<select (change)="selectCountry($event)" title="Select a country">
      <option *ngFor="let country of countryList">{{country.name}} 
      </option>
</select>


selectCountry(event) {

   let fireboxFix = event.target || event.srcElement;
   let indexToFind = (<HTMLSelectElement>fireboxFix).value;
   let testArray = [];
   for (let row of this.countryList) {
      testArray.push(row.name)
   }
   this.changeI = testArray.indexOf(indexToFind);
}
```